# MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR on commit

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-mq, python-multiprocessing, pymqi

I'm experiencing an issue while trying to use pymqi to send messages to IBM MQ.
A project i'm working on

- Reads from DB2
- Prepares data for `WorkerProcess`
- `WorkerProcess` does some decision based on that data and sens a message to MQ

When the `WorkerProcess` tries to commit the message for MQ, I get an error:

```
Stacktrace:
    worker_process.py:
        self.mq.commit()
    mq_service.py:
        self.qmgr.commit()
    pymqi/__init__.py line 1689, in commit
        raise MQMIError (rv[0], rv[1])
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2012: FAILED: MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR
```

*Code and stack trace has been typed by hand and can contain typos.*

Bellow code is a pseudo code of what I'm doing.

Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated.

main.py:

```
c_processors = []
for i in range(num_of_proccessors):
    p = WorkerProcess()
    p.start()
    c_processors.append(p)

for p in c_processors:
    p.join()
```

worker_process.py

```
class WorkerProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.mq = MQService()

    def run(self):
        self.mq.send_message('test')
        self.mq.commit()
        self.mq.close_connection()
```

mq_service.py

```
class MQService():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.connect()
        self.pmd = pymqi.MD()
        self.pmd.Format = pymqi.CMQC.MQFMT_STRING
        self.pmo = pymqi.PMO(Options=pymqi.CMQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING)
        self.pmo.Options |= pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT

    def connect(self):
        self._connect_to_qmgr(manager,chanel,host,port,user,password) #these arguments are retrieved from config
        self._q = pymqi.Queue(self.qmgr, queue_name) 

    def _connect_to_qmgr(self,manager,chanel,host,port,user,password):
        self.qmgr = pymqi.QueueManager(None)
        _cd = pymqi.CD()
        _cd.ChannelName = channel.encode('utf-8')
        _cd.ConnectionName = f"{host} ({port})".encode('utf-8')
        _cd.ChannelType = pymqi.CMQC.MQCHT_CLNTCONN
        _cd.TransportType = pymqi.CMQC.MQXPT_TCP
        _connect_options = pymqi.CMQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK

        _qmgr.connect_with_options(manager, cd=_cd, opts=_connect_options, user=user, password=password)

    def send_message(self, message):
        self._q.put(message, self.pmd, self.pmo)

    def commit(self):
        self.qmgr.commit()
    
    def rollback(self):
        self.qmgr.backout()

    def close_connection(self):
        self.qmgr.disconnect()
```

***EDIT:***
Additional information:

- I'm running IBM MQ client version 9.1.0.1.
- There are no errors in `AMQERR0*.LOG` files.
- LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set
- This error showed while refactoring the code.

**Below is the code that is working (before refactoring)**:

**Some arguments in function signature are replaced with (args*) for the sake of brevity and readability**

main.py:

```
def connect_to_mq():
    return MQService(args*)  # these arguments are read from Config file


def process_chunk(args*): 
    _mq = connect_to_mq()
    _mq.send_message('test')
    _mq.commit()
    _mq.close_connection()

c_processors = []
for i in range(num_of_proccessors):
    p = Process(target=process_chunk, args=(args*))
    p.start()
    c_processors.append(p)

for p in c_processors:
    p.join()
```

mq_service.py

```
class MQService():
    
    def __init__(self, args*):
        self.pmd = pymqi.MD()
        self.pmd.Format = pymqi.CMQC.MQFMT_STRING
        self.pmo = pymqi.PMO(Options=pymqi.CMQC.MQPMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING)
        self.pmo.Options |= pymqi.CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT
        self.connect_to_qmgr(args*)
        self.connect_to_queue(args*)


    def _connect_to_qmgr(self,manager,chanel,host,port,user,password):
        self.qmgr = pymqi.connect(manager, 
                                  chanel, 
                                  "%s (%s)" % (host, port), 
                                  user=user, 
                                  password=password)
   
    def connect_to_queue(q_name):
        self._q = pymqi.Queue(self.qmgr, q_name)

 
    def send_message(self, message):
        self._q.put(message, self.pmd, self.pmo)

    def commit(self):
        self.qmgr.commit()
    
    def rollback(self):
        self.qmgr.backout()

    def close_connection(self):
        self.qmgr.disconnect()
```

Comment: Do you have mq client libraries installed? Check for a file `AMQERR01.LOG` and review for errors.

Comment: Also ensure that your library path includes either the MQ install lib (32bit) or lib64 (64 bit).

Comment: Thank you for the help @JoshMc;
I forgot to mention that this error happened after code refactoring. I've eddited my question and added previous code that worked.
/var/mqm/errors/AMQERR01.log is empty.

Comment: What is the propose of adding `connect_options = pymqi.CMQC.MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK`?  This is documented as "The application and the local-queue-manager agent are part of the same unit of execution."  The error description states "The application is linked to the wrong libraries (threaded or nonthreaded)."  Is pymqi compiled to support multi threaded?

Comment: Hello,
If I don't use this option, I get MQRC_ALREADY_CONNECTED.
I found this solution in pymqi [documentation](https://dsuch.github.io/pymqi/examples.html#how-to-avoid-mqrc-already-connected)

Comment: I asked a 2nd question, can you reply to that as well.

Comment: Hmm I don't know; I haven't compiled it myself.
I was using pip to install it to virtualenvironment; pymqi version is 1.12.0
As for `MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK` [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/api/v1/content/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/constants/CMQC.html#MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK) says "This option indicates that connection and object handles allocated by one thread of a process can be used by other threads belonging to the same process."

Comment: Are you using a global transaction here? You mentioned DB2. You cannot use a MQCNO_HANDLE_SHARE_BLOCK hConn in a global transaction

Comment: Hello Morag,
Thanks for the input.
No; I'm not using global transactions.
Since then; I figured out what the problem is.
Library pymqi supports multithreading but it does not support multiprocessing.
 In the example that works, all connections to MQ are opened in parent process.
In the example that doesn't work, each process is trying to connect to MQ; and this seems to be the problem.